# 'sass' is not recognized error when running start script

Tags: html, css, npm, sass

I'm trying to create a command to compile scss into css more easily. I installed nodejs, npm and node-sass.

I then created this run script:

```json
"start": "sass ./sass/style.scss style.css --watch"
```

And run command:  `npm start` , also use `npm run scss`
but it returns this error:

```
'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ecommercesite@1.0.0 start: `sass ./sass/style.scss style.css --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ecommercesite@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.       
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

I also tried running the `npm install` command for node_modules but it continuously throws the same error.

I would be grateful if anyone help to solve this.

Comment: You should try node-sass instead, or npx node-sass if you are doing it from the command line and don't have node-sass installed globally

Comment: i'm already installed node-sass globally using  "npm install -g node-sass"

Comment: @Lk77 _No._ `node-sass` is deprecated and _shouldn't_ be used. `sass` is the current version.

Comment: @AKK i know that, but the OP asked about node-sass, so i'm answering about that

Answer (score 0):

Try

```json
"start": "node-sass ./sass/style.scss style.css --watch"
```

instead, or if you want to run it from the command line:

```sh
npx node-sass ./sass/style.scss style.css --watch
```